# Knockout afterRender fires only once

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, knockout.js, knockout-3.0

I have this simple ViewModel:

```
 export class ViewModel {
    public arr : KnockoutObservableArray<Dtos>;
    constructor() {
        this.arr = ko.observableArray<Dtos>(null);
        ko.applyBindings(this);
        this.init();
    }

    private init() {
        var self = this;
        ajaxCall().done(item => {
                self.arr(item.Dtos);                   
            });
    }

    public initPlugins() {
         jQuery(".external-events > li")
            .each(function() {
                if ($(this).attr("event-draggable") == "false")
                    return true;
                jQuery(this).draggable({
                zIndex: 999,
                revert: true, // will cause the event to go back to its
                revertDuration: 0 // original position after the drag
            });
         });
    }
}
```

This vm is getting applied to this markup:

```
<ul class="external-events" data-bind="foreach: {arr, afterRender: initPlugins($data)}">
    <li event-draggable="false">
        <div class="bg-info">
            <span data-bind="text: Name"></span>
        </div>
        <ul  class="external-events" data-bind="foreach: moreStuff">
            <li>
                <div class="bg-info">
                    <span data-bind="text: Name"></span>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

The problem is that the `afterRender` event of the `foreach` binding is only getting fired once, obviously after `ko.applyBindings` but the DOM is not ready yet so we can't init the `jQuery.ui` draggable.

According to Ko documentation, `afterRender` should fire every time the `observableArray` (belonging to the corresponding foreach) changes but it's not happening.

Eventually I got it working by initialising the draggable in the `ajax.done` after I populate the array, but I feel like it's not the correct way to do it, and nonetheless the problem still exists, `afterRender` not firing on array update.

Any ideas would be much appreciated.

PS: By array i obviously mean `ko.observableArray`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in your

```
foreach: {arr, afterRender: initPlugins($data)}
```

`afterRender` expects a function as parameter, but you are invoking the function by calling it with data as parameter, change it to:

```
foreach: {arr, afterRender: initPlugins }
```

`afterRender` method will be called with 2 parameters by knockout:

An array of the inserted DOM elements, the data item against which they are being bound

Comment: thank you, it works! Is there any clean way I can access the ViewModel inside the afterRender?